# MSSQL and Entity framework syncing PK on multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've been working with Entity framework in C# trying to figure out how to join two tables together. I found a reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715646.aspx on how to do this.  Problem is, the two tables have PKs that are not in sync which seems to be a requirement.  I've never had to worry about syncing PKs from two tables in a database before.  I know I can turn off identity insert on one table but I see comments from numerous people that this is a very bad idea.  If I'm not supposed to do this, then how do I accomplish syncing the PKs in each of the tables?

I have two tables in a database:

User

- pkID (int)
- FirstName (varchar)
- LastName (varchar)
- Email (varchar)
- ...

LockedFlags  (locking fields in user from being edited)

- pkID
- fkUserID
- bFirstName (bool)
- bLastName (bool)
- bEmail (bool)

I'm curious on why people thing that removing the identity insert on a table is a bad idea... if I'm relying on MSSQL to assign a PK then I could see an instance when I'm inserting a record into the database where the second table write could get a different value when dealing with multiple writes...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have orphaned rows in the LockedFlags table, like a row with a user ID that points to a user that has been deleted. Depending on how the relationship is setup it can also be true for the reverse.

If you have a entity where the 2 tables are combined into a single class, loading the entity set will query both tables and require matching pairs of rows.

Your LockedFlags probably has a User property which it is trying to load and cannot find in the user table.

Table options:
Note: I'm using MSSQL equivalent as I don't know MYSQL.

Comments regarding your data model:
I don't know how MYWSQL handles record locking but if it is anything like MSSQL, you do not have to worry about manually handling.

I would strongly suggest re-looking at your data model if you're going to use it as is. Just using a single table would be best if you really want to manually lock individual row fields?

Edit:

```
ALTER TABLE LockFlags ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_LockFlags_User FOREIGN KEY
    (
    UserID
    ) REFERENCES User
    (
    pkID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
```

Comment: I'm using MSSQL...  The problem I have is that these tables are modified outside of the entity framework in another application.  I'm writing a web front end for it now which is why I'm using the entity framework at this point.  My main issue is that the LockedFlags table doesn't have a record for every user record.  It has a record only when a field has been locked down...  So now I'm having to go back and work on this which is why I'm trying to figure out how to update the LockedFlags table with correct information and then trying to figure out how best to keep this working right...

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the last part.  I'm locking the text entry boxes, not the record...

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to achieve. Regardless if you want to maintain data integrity you can add a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. I've added sample code to my original answer.

Comment: Be careful, this will probably break the API that is responsible for the inconsistent data.